# Nuget Package Versioning - Max Integer for Major/Minor/Patch?

Tags: nuget, artifactory, nuget-package, semantic-versioning

Is there an upper limit to the major/minor/patch components of a Nuget package version?

For instance, can I create MyPackage.1.99999.99999 and upload to Artifactory or Nuget.org and clients will have no issues referencing the package?

Answer (score 2):

Nuget is [using Semver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning) as its versioning scheme.
Semver 2.0 [does not](https://github.com/semver/semver/issues/79) define a size for the numeric identifiers.
It does recommend a limit of 255 characters for the entire string in its [FAQ](https://semver.org/#does-semver-have-a-size-limit-on-the-version-string).
Since this is not part of the spec you can expect different implementations to have their own limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is an upper limit to the version components of an NuGet package.

NuGet [parses the Version](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/b56eacca7b4d73463631ec82c4b52867c13482b2/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Versioning/NuGetVersionFactory.cs#L59) using [System.Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=net-6.0#properties). Since the Major/Minor/Build-Properties are `Int32`, the highest possible Version of an NuGet package would be `2147483647.2147483647.2147483647`

There is also an (at the time of writing) [open Issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/11503) on the missing documentation on this in the NuGet Issue Tracker.